# Is there a way to change the behavior of matrices globally?

Tags: matrix, options

For instance, I want that `Dot` would be used as default multiplication of matrices instead of element-by-element multiplication. Similarly, I want any function (such as `Sin [M]`) when acting on a matrix, would return the same as `MatrixFunction [Sin,M]` instead of acting on the elements separately. Is it possible?

Maybe there is such global option?

Comment: Independent of whether this is possible, it would be a very bad idea to enforce that. Better not waste your time for trying to beat the system.

Comment: I think it might be useful (for yourself, and for others coming to this QA) if you can identify exactly *why* it is that you would want to do something of this nature. If it is to save a number of keystrokes, this is one thing and may not make it worth your efforts, but if it is for another reason that seemingly carries enough worth, that is another story entirely.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, you can do the kind of thing you want with `UpValues`, essentially defining your own matrix type. But not exactly what you want, since `Times` is `Orderless`, and matrix multiplication doesn't commute. This is an example of the rigor that a mindless CAS needs. Humans can use ambiguous notation, but computer notation must clearly distinguish between commutative and non-commutative multiplication.

Comment: Also, functions such as `Sin` are `Listable`. Messing with this would do massive damage.

Comment: @BobHanlon You wouldn't have to mess with the `Listable` attribute, as you would be making your matrices something that doesn't have `List` as its head. The `Orderless` attribute of `Times` is much more problematic.

Comment: @BobHanlon You could defeat `Listable` by wrapping your matrix. Not `Orderless`, though.

Comment: Guys, pretend the matrix types I use is commutative. So, this can be done?